# Do not return any entries if there is even one entry matching a certain criteria based on 2 different colums

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have this query which searches for records that Col5 does not equal 'Finished'

`=QUERY(sort(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/...", "SSI ASN Tracker!a2:H"),7,TRUE),"SELECT * WHERE Col5 <> 'Finished'")`

I have come to realize that my logic is not sound. I actually need to ensure no entries are returned at all if there is even one record where Col5 matches 'Finished'. Unfortunately I have no unique column. The combination of `Col1` and `Col2` is the unique value. I assume I need to group based on the the combined values of 'Col1`and`Col2`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect ("no entries are returned at all if there is even one record where Col5 matches 'Finished'") with a conditional:

```
=if(isna(match("Finished", importrange("...", "SheetName!E2:E"), 0),  query(importrange(...), "select ..."), )
```

The condition checks that there is no match of "Finished" in the column E. If this is the case, then the query runs. Otherwise the output is blank.

Comment: This is what I have... but I still get results showing "Started" even though there is another entry showing "Finished"....

Comment: =if(isna(match("Finished", importrange("https://docs.google.com/...", "SSI ASN Tracker!E2:E"), 0)),  QUERY(sort(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/...", "SSI ASN Tracker!a2:H"),7,TRUE),"SELECT * WHERE Col5 <> 'Finished'") )

Comment: You can check the formula piece by piece: what does "match" part output? Etc.